# Android TabLayout Click Events

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

I have several tabs in a TabLayout. xml:

```
      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/info_tab"
            android:icon="@drawable/info"
            android:clickable="true"/>
...
```

and I'm getting very confused with how to set up an OnClickListener for these. all online sources assume I'm using TabHost, but those functions don't apply to TabLayout. Should I use TabHost instead? Or what would an OnClickListener look like for TabLayout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this...

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

and in onTabSelected you can write the code to make the user go to that fragment when he clicks on that tab name..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
using MyTabLayout = Android.Support.Design.Widget.TabLayout;
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);            
        var tabLayout = FindViewById<MyTabLayout>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.AddTab(tabLayout.NewTab().SetText("CNN"));
        tabLayout.AddTab(tabLayout.NewTab().SetText("BBC"));
        tabLayout.AddTab(tabLayout.NewTab().SetText("ABC7News"));
        tabLayout.TabGravity = MyTabLayout.GravityFill;
        tabLayout.TabSelected += TabLayout_TabSelected;
    }



    private void TabLayout_TabSelected(object sender, MyTabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Tab.Position)
        {
            case 0: ShowAlert("0");  break;
            case 1: ShowAlert("1"); break;
            case 2: ShowAlert("2"); break;
        }
    }
```

sliding_tabs - `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />`